# Twitter message reply with direct message link not carrying over conversation context

Tags: twitter, dialogflow-es

I have a Dialogflow and Twitter integration and all seems to be working fine, except for one scenario.

I have an intent that is looking for negative statements from tweets that mention the Twitter user linked to the Dialogflow integration (lets call it @Target). The purpose of this is to then reply back with a Twitter direct message (DM) link, inviting the person to engage in conversation to further explore their problem.

The scenario steps that do not work are:

1. Send Tweet to @Target saying for example "Your service is really bad". At this point, the output context is "negative-sentiment" if DF recognises it.
2. If that is the case, DF then sends back a response with a link that will allow the user to open up a DM session to further explain their issue. In this example they may have a gas supply issue.
3. The user opens the link in the tweet reply to start the DM.
4. At this point, I am looking for an explanation of the issue, for example "My gas supply has been cut off". However, if I do that, it does not recognise the intent. I have to at this point re-enter the phrase "Your service is really bad" to get it to register the "negative-sentiment" context, then I can move on.

What does work, is if I start with a DM stating "Your service is really bad", followed by "My gas supply has been cut off". It's almost as if clicking on the reply to tweet either forgets the context or its actually a different DF session that is created once we fall into the DM.

So, has anyone seen this behaviour before? Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DialogFlow, but this sounds like you need to set up a Twitter Direct Message Welcome message to ask the user for more information? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/welcome-messages/overview

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is when they do offer more information after switching to DM, i.e. "My gas supply has been cut off", it does not remember the negative sentiment context that drove the customer to this point in the first place. But I think your suggestion as a separate point will help with the overall customer experience.

Answer (score 2):

When you attempt to switch from @mentions to DMs on Twitter keep in mind the sessions don't carry over (they are separate sessions) so what you'll need to do going forward is keep track of usernames on the backend in order to connect the two distinct sessions.